# using setInnerXHTMl or FBML to show image with specified height/width

Tags: facebook

I am trying to show an image of a specified height and width. Heres the code that I am using:

```
function showpic(var1)
{
    piclink="<span><img src=\""+var1+"\" align=\"bottom\" width=\"400\" 
    height=\"300\" /></span> "; 

    document.getElementById('big_pic').setInnerXHTML(piclink);
}
```

where var1=absolute link of the image

The problem is, the height/width is getting sanitized (read removed). What can I do ? Please let me know. Thanks.

-
ahsan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved using :

```
myimg = document.getElementById('img_tag');
myimg.setStyle({height: '300px', width: '400px'});
```

thanks

-
ahsan